# Reduce two characters in a timestamp

Tags: batch-file

I have a situation where I need to reduce two characters from the timestamp.

Code used   : `D%date:~6,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.T%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%`

Output      : `D20140514.T071830`

Requirement : `D140514.T071830`

Please help me achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you have provided is either incomplete or not yielding what you claim. %date:~6,2% may yield `20` or `14` depending on your date-settings. Regardless, it will be 2 characters long, not 4. The method of setting `%hr%` is not shown, so it's likely to be empty. Assuming that you are using dd/mm/yyyy format date, you should use `D%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.T%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%` to get the required format; you'd need `D%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.T%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%` for the format you claim - and that doesn't count spaces replacing leading 0.

Comment: Hello Magoo, I am a beginner in the batch front so pardon my ignorance. yes, D%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.T%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% was the initial line. Thanks for the answer. D%date:~8,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%.T%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value^|find "="') do set a=%%a
set a=D%a:~2,6%.T%a:~8,6%
echo %a%
```